# Parse json array in SQL to extract corresponding value of a specified name

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server, parsing

I want to extract the following json into a table like below. There may be multiple entries under the LIABILITY section so each one will generate a new row. The metrics under the RESPONSE/SUMMARY section will repeat for each one of the LIABILITY entries. I'm not sure how to extract the SUMMARY metric - Right now, I want to designate the NAME (e.g. 'Number of books') I want under DATASET, and pull the corresponding value (e.g., 27)

I am using Microsoft SQL Server

```
Report ID    |   File ID   | Number of books
123456           ABC01       27
123456           ABC02       27
```

```
 {
 "RESPONSE": {
    "@ReportIdentifier": "123456",
    "@ReportFirstIssuedDate": "2021-02-12",
    },

   "LIABILITY": [
      {
        "@LiabilityID": "TRADE001",
        "@BorrowerID": "Borrower01",
        "@FileID": "ABC01"
      }, 

      {
        "@LiabilityID": "TRADE001",
        "@BorrowerID": "Borrower01",
        "@FileID": "ABC02"
      }
                      ], 
   
   "SUMMARY": {
      "@BorrowerID": "Borrower01",
      "@_Name": "Attributes",
      "_DATA_SET": [
        {
          "@_Name": "Number of books",
          "@_Value": "27"
        },
        {
          "@_Name": "Average age of borrow",
          "@_Value": "35"
        },
        {
          "@_Name": "Number of messages",
          "@_Value": "4"
        }
```

Comment: You need to say what kind of a database you're using.

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to be pretty and you'd probably be better off parsing this json in some kind of backend code, e.g. C#, Python, JavaScript, whatever.

Now that you're warned, you're going to want to use a couple of JSON related functions in SQL:

- JSON_VALUE - extract a scalar value from the json object (e.g. the report identifier)
- OPENJSON - open the json object/array as if it was a table

We end up with:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(json, '$.RESPONSE."@ReportIdentifier"') AS ReportID
     , JSON_VALUE(Liability.value, '$."@FileID"') AS FileID
     , Summary.Value AS NumberOfBooks
 FROM so
CROSS
APPLY OPENJSON(json, '$.LIABILITY') AS Liability
CROSS
APPLY OPENJSON(json, '$.SUMMARY."_DATA_SET"') 
      WITH
      (
         Name NVARCHAR(25) '$."@_Name"'
       , Value NVARCHAR(25) '$."@_Value"'
      ) AS Summary
WHERE Summary.name = 'Number of books'
```

Here you see @ReportIdentifier can be extracted directly from your json object using a straightforward path. Since you want a row per each liability array element, we have to extract that using OPENJSON and then use JSON_VALUE to extract @FileID from each of the elements. Finally with the summary nested object we can't simply extract value because this is a dictionary and we just want the number of books. I don't know whether Number of Books dict entry is always first in your data set, so I opted for translating the whole array into a table and then filter only for the rows where the name is 'Number of Books'.

[Here's a working demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b7a38a07bc8a224d17158cd9b9f5c869)